# How do I make a server accept requests after sending a response?

Tags: python, sockets

I have a client program that connects to the server socket and sends a string to be evaluated in the server.py file. Once evaluated, the server will send back a response. The client takes the response and displays it and then sends another string to the server. However, the server does not accept any other requests after evaluation. Here's the server.py file:

```
import socket
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.ERROR)
def binomial(n,m):
    b = 1
    for i in range(0,m):
        b = b * (n-i) // (i+1)
    return b

# 1. Create Socket
port= 12345
listner=socket.socket()

# 2. Bind with ip address and port number
listner.bind(("", port))
# 3. Generate listener
listner.listen(0)
# 4. Waits for a connection request

while True:
    (sock, address)=listner.accept()   # waits for a connection request
                                    # When successful, it returns a socket
                                    # and an address to use to communicate
                                    # with the client
# 4.1 Get data from the client
    print(address)
    logging.info("Connection established with"+str(address))
    bytes = sock.recv(2048)
    client_data=""

    while len(bytes)>0:
        client_data+=bytes.decode()     #UTF-8
        bytes=sock.recv(2048)
# 4.2 Parse the data from the client
    list_of_parts=client_data.split(" ")
    # "12 6"    => ["12", "6"]
    # "12  6"   => ["12", "", "6"]
    # "twelve six" => ["twelve" "six"]
    if len(list_of_parts)!=2:
        # signal an error
        # error response
        response_status="E"
        response_message="Incorrect number of parameters sent"
        logging.error("Incorrect number of parameters sent")
    else:
        try:
            # 4.3 Compute the binomial function
            # try to convert the two elements to numeric
            # compute and generate response
            result=binomial(int(list_of_parts[0]), int(list_of_parts[1]))
            response_status="B"
            response_message=str(result)
        except:
            # signal a coversion problem or computation problem
            # error response
            response_status = "E"
            response_message = "Conversion or computation error"

    # 4.4 Create a response
    message=response_status+response_message
    response_byte=message.encode()
    # 4.5 Send the response to the client
    sock.sendall(response_byte)
    # 4.6 Signal close of the writing side of the socket
    sock.shutdown(1) # signal close of the writing side of the socket

    # 5. close the socket and terminate program
    sock.close()
```

I am getting this error:

```
BrokenPipeError: [WinError 10058] A request to send or receive data was disallowed because the socket had already been shut down in that direction with a previous shutdown call
```

How can I make it so that the server can accept another request after the first response?

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the process of receiving/sending data in a loop. Try this:

```
import socket
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.ERROR)
def binomial(n,m):
    b = 1
    for i in range(0,m):
        b = b * (n-i) // (i+1)
    return b

# 1. Create Socket
port= 12345
listner=socket.socket()

# 2. Bind with ip address and port number
listner.bind(("", port))
# 3. Generate listener
listner.listen(1)
# 4. Waits for a connection request

while True:
    (sock, address) = listner.accept()   # waits for a connection request
                                    # When successful, it returns a socket
                                    # and an address to use to communicate
                                    # with the client
# 4.1 Get data from the client
    print(address)
    logging.info("Connection established with"+str(address))

    while True:
        bytes = sock.recv(2048)
        client_data = ""

        while len(bytes) > 0:
            client_data += bytes.decode()  # UTF-8
            bytes = sock.recv(2048)
            # 4.2 Parse the data from the client
        list_of_parts = client_data.split(" ")
        # "12 6"    => ["12", "6"]
        # "12  6"   => ["12", "", "6"]
        # "twelve six" => ["twelve" "six"]
        if len(list_of_parts) != 2:
            # signal an error
            # error response
            response_status = "E"
            response_message = "Incorrect number of parameters sent"
            logging.error("Incorrect number of parameters sent")
        else:
            try:
                # 4.3 Compute the binomial function
                # try to convert the two elements to numeric
                # compute and generate response
                result = binomial(int(list_of_parts[0]), int(list_of_parts[1]))
                response_status = "B"
                response_message = str(result)
            except:
                # signal a coversion problem or computation problem
                # error response
                response_status = "E"
                response_message = "Conversion or computation error"

        # 4.4 Create a response
        message = response_status + response_message
        response_byte = message.encode()
        # 4.5 Send the response to the client
        sock.sendall(response_byte)
    # 4.6 Signal close of the writing side of the socket
    sock.shutdown(1)  # signal close of the writing side of the socket
    # break this loop when you want
    # 5. close the socket and terminate program
    sock.close()
```

I hope this helps !